# 74190 up/down decade counter starts from 5

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, counter

[image]I've been connected pins input A and C into VCC so the logical number is 1 and input B and input D with 0. The counter starts with 5, but it doesn't clock or change from number 5 into 0 (5,4,3,2,1,0,5,4,3,2,1,0) as I need.

What should I do for this 74190 so it will count down from 5 into 0 and so on?

Comment: It is way easier for users to help you, if you add a schematic to s show us, what you have done so far. Please use the integrated schematic tool to do so, it is very easy to use!

Comment: thanks for your advice. Now I've been added screenshot from my circuit :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the number and then stop loading and start counting down. Thus check the sequence of the load(not), CTEN(not) and clock pins.

- First load low
- Then load high
- Then CTEN low
- Then clocks

  Also  make sure D/U is high.

By the way, all that is in the datasheet:
[image]